# Collection View Covering Tab Bar

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, xcode8

I have a tab bar with three options, and when I attempt to go to the profile page, the bottom tab bar is covered by the collection view that I have programmatically added in. How do I make sure that the tab bar is not covered by this collection?

Here is the ProfilePageVC:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)


        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        // self.lowerView.addSubview(collectionView)
        self.lowerView.insertSubview(collectionView, belowSubview: self.view)
        self.reloadInputViews()

    }
```

Here is where my tab bar code is (It is in just the regular default VC)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

    var homeVC : UIViewController!
    var testVC : UIViewController!
    var profileVC : UIViewController!

    var viewControllers : [UIViewController]!

    //What tab we are pressing
    var selectedVC : Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        homeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomePage")
        testVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RecordPage")
        profileVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfilePage")

        viewControllers = [homeVC, testVC, profileVC]

        buttons[selectedVC].isSelected = true
        hasPressedTab(buttons[selectedVC])
    }

    @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!

    @IBAction func hasPressedTab(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let previousVC = selectedVC
        selectedVC = sender.tag
        buttons[previousVC].isSelected = false

        let previousIndex = viewControllers[previousVC]

        //removes from previous VC
        previousIndex.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        previousIndex.view.removeFromSuperview()
        previousIndex.removeFromParentViewController()

        //accesses current button selected
        sender.isSelected = true

        let vc = viewControllers[selectedVC]
        addChildViewController(vc)

        //addjusts size of VC to match the added contentView
        vc.view.frame = contentView.bounds
        contentView.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

Here are images describing the problem:

The tan area is the lowerView

With-Out Collection View as a subview: 
https://ibb.co/gH2dWF

With CollectionView as a subview:
https://ibb.co/jWh1ka

Comment: Why post iOS questions on Rune-Server bruh

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "lowerView" refers to, but have you tried just adding the subview to the view?

```
self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
```

Comment: Yes I have and that is what is currently there, however it covers my tab bar, I have included two photos in the original post to explain more of the situation

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem may be with this line:

```
self.lowerView.insertSubview(collectionView, belowSubview: self.view)
```

Why are you trying to add it in the lowerView? I can't actually see what the lowerView actually means in the code, but the normal flow would be to add the collectionView as a subview of `self.view`. Maybe the lowerView frame is actually over the tabBar and that's why its covering the tab bar.

The code would be:

```
self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
```

If you need to send the collection view to the back, you can send it with:

```
self.view.sendSubview(toBack: collectionView)
```

Comment: That unfortunately did not work. Here are two images that show the problem. Here is with no collectionview in the subview:https://ibb.co/jWh1ka
https://ibb.co/gH2dWF and here it is with collectionview in the subview https://ibb.co/jWh1ka